# Mysql ERROR: 1093

Tags: mysql

Help me pls.
the exercise is: 
"Modify the database so that all players who have scored more than 3 goals per match earning a 5% increase in your salary."
How do I do this? I tried with this code but he Is giving error

```
 update tbplayer
 set salary_player=(salary_player*1.0)
 where tbplayer.name_player in (
 select tbjplayer.name_player
 from tbjplayer inner join tbplay
 on tbplayer.cod_player = tbplay.cod_player
 where tbplay.numberGoalsPlayer >= 3)
```

table structure:
http://textuploader.com/d5vlh

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tbjogador' for update in FROM clause  0.000 sec

Comment: You can't query and update the same table, hence the error. Can you share the table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update a table used  for selecting the value  you need but you can force mysql to create dinamically a temporary table for this

```
    update tbplayer

      set salary_player=(salary_player*1.0)
      where tbplayer.name_player in ( select t.my_name  from ( 

            select tbjplayer.name_player my_name
            from tbjplayer inner join tbplay
            on tbplayer.cod_player = tbplay.cod_player
            where tbplay.numberGoalsPlayer >= 3)  t )
```

Comment: sorry brother, I'm new here... and I just accept your answer

Comment: @MarcoAntonio  many thanks  .. i usually post instruction for new user ..so you can begin to obtain  points  and know better SO